# Can I call .NET-functions from PHP on Windows Azure?

Tags: php, .net, azure

I'm currently evaluating the Windows Azure platform. The situation is this: We have a couple of .NET-DLLs with functions which we would like to expose as webservices for our clients. Since all our webservice experience is in PHP though, we would love to just call the .NET-functions from PHP and handle the webstuff in PHP.

I know this is possible via COM or Phalanger. But is it also possible for PHP applications deployed on Windows Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this, but I think that the amount of effort in "fixing stuff to make it work" will be equal to just exposing everything as a .NET web service.

Comment: You might be right. It's probably time to pick up a .NET-book and start learning.